# Once the last mythos card is flipped, is there no point to continuing the game?

Tags: eldritch-horror

Since most (or all) mysteries require waiting until the end of the mythos phase to officially complete them, is there no point to continuing the game once you flip the final mythos card and still haven't solved the first 3 mysteries? The exception to giving up the moment the final mythos is flipped seems to be when the ancient one awakens and you stand a chance to defeat him in that final round after the last mythos is flipped (since defeating the ancient one appears to end the game immediately in the investigators' favor).

Do I have this all correct?

Edit: from the Eldritch faq under **Ancient Ones & Mysteries**

> Q. Do effects that “advance the active Mystery” or “solve the active Mystery” affect the Final Mystery?
>
> A. No. The Final Mystery is not a Mystery card nor is it considered the active Mystery. As such, effects that advance or solve the active Mystery do not affect the Final Mystery.

This seems to support the treatment of Final Mysteries as a different entity as normal Mysteries.

Answer (score 2):

> Since most (or all) mysteries require waiting until the end of the mythos phase to officially complete them, is there no point to continuing the game once you flip the final mythos card and still haven't solved the first 3 mysteries?

In theory this is covered by the Reference Guide under *Winning/Losing*.

In practice, the official errata explains this:

> If a Mythos card cannot be drawn during the Mythos Phase, the Mythos Phase ends. Then, if investigators have not won the game, investigators lose the game.

So what happens is:

- The mythos phase skips right to the end.
- At this moment a Mystery card may say "At the end of the Mythos Phase, if [something], solve this Mystery". If this was the last mystery, the Ancient One sheet will usually say that you win.
- Anyway, the rules say that you lose, because you had no Mythos Card to draw.
- BUT the rules also say that if you win and lose at the same time, you win. (again *Winning/Losing* in the Reference Guide)

So if that was your last mystery, and you solved it, then you win.

As for beating the Ancient One: Yes, if a game component says you win, then you win. That's the actual rule (*Winning/Losing*).

Waiting until the end of Mythos Phase to win, is not a rule - it's written separately on each Ancient One's sheet.

Comment: I don't see any mention in the Winning/Losing section that says if you win and lose, you win. The errata faq says outright "No. If investigators lose the game while resolving a Mythos card, the Mythos Phase has not yet ended, and the third Mystery is not yet solved."

Comment: @Joey

>The game immediately ends when an effect specifies that “Investigators 
  win the game,” or “Investigators lose the game.”

>In the rare circumstance that both of these effects happen at the 
same time, investigators win the game.

Comment: @Joey If you lose _while_ resolving the myhos card, then the mythos card haven't ended yet. It ends after resolving the card.

Comment: My point is that the actual win after completing the last mystery doesn't occur until the 'end of the mythos phase', so you clearly can't win because you won't reach the end of the mythos phase before you lose from having no draw pile. A large number of steps fall between drawing that mythos card and reaching the end of the mythos phase, so I find it a stretch to consider these two happening 'at the same time.'

Answer (score 1):

Solving any mystery happens at the end of the Mythos phase. Let's say you have only one card left only two things can happen:

1. If you *have solved* the final mystery, then you have to survive that Mythos card event.  If you do, you win the game.  If not, you lose.
2. If you *have not solved* the final mystery, then you have lost the game. There is no point in doing the last round as you cannot draw a new mythos card.

Comment: The "final" mystery is stated as being solved after certain conditions and doesn't explicitly say "at the end of the mythos phase."  This omission strongly implies to me that it doesn't require investigators to survive a mythos after completing it and seems to make thematic sense as you've directly beaten an active awake ancient one, so the threat is directly neutralized. Do you have documentation referring to the final mystery requiring a completed mythos after the fact?

Comment: I view the final mystery as a super set of the normal mysteries thus the same rules that apply to mysteries apply to the final one, including that it is resolved at the end of the mythos phase. However, I have no backing for my reading of the rules beside the first rule of cooperative games which states that *if a rule is ambiguous, its reading is the least favourable to the players*.

Comment: I found a good reference in the faq that clarifies the difference between mystery and final mystery which I'll edit in the main question. It states final mysteries are not mysteries, so perhaps implies they should be treated differently here.